# Trying to remove bad data using countif function

Tags: excel, countif

First, thank you for the help in solving this problem. It's pretty simple but I'm just not getting it.

In excel, I have 2 tabs. In the first tab, I have rows of personel data (job title, country of business, Industry, etc.)

In the second tab, I have a column of prohibited titles. These are titles that don't match the criteria we want.

I'd like to create a formula that checks the rows in tab 1 against the prohibited titles in tab 2. If the data matches, I'd like it to return 'N' in column A, which signals that we should remove that row of data. Title information is found in row F on tab 1.

My various countif functions aren't working and I'm not sure why.

Various countif formulas, like

=COUNTIF(F:F,"*'Bad Titles!'A:A*")

Produces N for all titles we want to disregard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MATCH it is quicker:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2,'Bad Titles!'A:A,0)),"N","")
```

If the matches are partial then:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Bad Titles!'$A$1:$A$100,F2))),"N","")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I think it partially solves the problem. The problem is that the titles are partial matches, so the solution might require additional steps. For example, a title might be "assistant to the vice president" - I would flag that because it has an assistant in the complete title. After digging further, it might be more complicated than I thought, requiring a macro or something

Comment: Yes! The second formula is perfect. Scott, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ckontes please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.